# PostgreSQL: Return a trigger error (raise exception) in JSON format

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, plpgsql

I'm trying to find out is it possible in *ANY* way to exit a trigger procedure (return/raise exception, whatever) with a JSON output. I want to do something like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION users_do_before_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.username = '' OR NEW.full_name = '' OR NEW.email = '') THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION json_build_object('error', 'All fields are mandatory.');
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER users_bi_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE users_do_before_insert();
```

So, the expected output would be:

```
{"error" : "All fields are mandatory."}
```

I would appreciate **any** help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RAISE` [statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) requires format string or `USING` clause

```
RAISE EXCEPTION '%', json_build_object(..);
RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE=json_build_object(..);
```

Comment: God bless ya! Thanks